# Multiple PWA for an Angular site

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I'm building an Angular site with PWA. In this, user have different forms to fill.

Example-

- mysite.com/form1
- mysite.com/form2
- mysite.com/form3

When user installs PWA app after visiting first path, Form1 will be installed. Similarly, user can install 3 different PWAs.

I've tried creating 3 manifest files with different "*scope*" & "*start_url* "

Inside First Manifest file:

```
"scope": "./form1",
"start_url": "./form1",
```

Inside Second Manifest file:

```
"scope": "./form2",
"start_url": "./form2",
```

& linked them in "*index.html* " like:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest-form1.webmanifest">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest-form2.webmanifest">
```

But by implementing this, only first linked manifest is working.

Please suggest how can I achieve this. I've only one angular application & not looking to create new angular project for every form as most of other things will be same across them. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you ever receive an answer or find a solution to this?